# How to notify foreground activiy with event from background activity?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have background activity in which I'm listening to Gps Location. Above it I have map activity.
How can I notify the map activity when an event occurred in the background after the activity already started?

- I guess that this kind of question already been answered, but I tried googeling with many key words with no success, so sorry if it is duplicate. I'll appreciate references to other answer as well.

Thanks.

Comment: I hope you mean background `Service` and not background `Activity`?

Comment: I guess I'm not using services. The background activity has other functionality then just listen to gps location it is the app main activity. and map activity is just on of many other activities that the main "background" activity is starting.

Answer (score 2):

You probably shouldn't use an activity to perform a background task, it is extremely inefficient.  I would recommend using a [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) and communicate with [Intents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) and a [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html).  Services are designed to perform these kinds of operations.

You could also use an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and communicate with the main thread with a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html).

(All links are to the Android documentation for your reference)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a broadcast to pass your data in an `Intent` (which is the main unit of communication between components in the Android platform). Check out the docs for [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html), it does a good job of spelling it out.

Also, worth noting, if your sender and activity are in the same process, you can use a [LocalBroadcastManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) to avoid IPC overhead.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, do you know if broadcast is the common and the efficient solution for this problem?

Comment: An `Intent` is the main unit of communication between components in the Android platform, so yes, using a broadcast to send an `Intent` is a good way to accomplish this.